# Fast Function resembling a^b

Tags: java, performance, function, pow

This is kind of obscure, but I need a function that can be computed very quickly and resembles  a^b where a is between 0 and 1 and b is very large. It will be calculated for one a at a time for many b's. Ideally, the result would be within 0.4%. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `b` an integer? Alternatively, is `b` large enough where it can be rounded to an integer?

Comment: yes, b is large enough to be rounded to an integer

Comment: Perfect, then take a look the [binary exponentiation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). With the right optimizations, it can probably be made faster than `Math.pow()`.

Comment: Thank you. should I do it recursively, or will that end up really slow and prone to stackoverflows?

Comment: It won't be deep enough to cause a stackoverflow. But I do suggest an iterative implementation over a recursive one.

Comment: a stack overflow occurred before 1000000 for b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling my comments into an answer:

Since you mention that `b` is large enough to be rounded to an integer, then one approach is to use the [Binary Exponentiation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) by squaring.

`Math.pow()` is slow because it needs to handle non-integral powers. So might be possible to do better in your case because you can utilize the integer powering algorithms.

---

As always, benchmark your implementation to see if it actually is faster than `Math.pow()`.

---

Here's an implementation that the OP found:

```
public static double pow(double a, int b) {
    double result = 1;
    while(b > 0) {
        if (b % 2 != 0) {
            result *= a;
            b--;
        } 
        a *= a;
        b /= 2;
    }

    return result;

}
```

---

Here's my quick-and-dirty (unoptimized) implementation:

```
public static double intPow(double base,int pow){
    int c = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(pow);

    pow <<= c;

    double value = 1;
    for (; c < 32; c++){
        value *= value;
        if (pow < 0)
            value *= base;
        pow <<= 1;
    }

    return value;
}
```

This should work on all positive `pow`. But I haven't benchmarked it against `Math.pow()`.

Comment: I found an implementation that looks like it should be fast, but it is about 10% slower than Math.pow

Comment: Oops, I accidentally overrode your edit. Gimme a sec to add it back.

Comment: @Fractaly The one I threw together is almost the same as the one you found. So it might or may not be any better. That said, there's still room for optimizations.

Comment: yours is about 5 times faster. I'm not quite sure how it works, but it's accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Math.pow(double, double) calls StrictMath.pow(double, double), which is declared native. pow(double, int) can optimize with binary exponential, but I doubt there is a fast method for pow(double, double).

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, I'm aware of that. Which makes it tricky, because you need the algorithmic advantage of the integer algorithm to beat a potentially assembly-hand-tuned implementation of `Math.pow()`.

Comment: In my application, pow(double,int) is acceptable. However, when I tried pow(0.99,1000000) for Mystical's implementation, it returned 1.0. I think it has some rounding problems.

Comment: It is actually very close to 0.0

Comment: @Fractaly Both are returning `0.0` for me. So I think it's correct.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I tried to modify the algorithm and messed it up. Fixed it. Thanks for the algorithm. It is working significantly faster.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific case ("calculated for one a at a time for many b's") I would suggest following approach:

Prepare table data to be used later in particular calculations:

- determine N such that 2^N is less than b for each possible b.
- calculate table t: t[n]=a^(2^n) for each n which is less than N. This is effectively done as t[k+1]=t[k]*t[k].

Calculate a^b:

- using binary representation of b, compute a^b as t[i1]*t[i2]*...*t[ik] where i1..ik are positions of non-zero bits in binary representation of b.

The idea is to reuse values of a^(2^n) for different b's.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache FastMath](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/util/FastMath.html#pow(double,%20int)) offers `double pow(double d, int e)` function for case when the exponent is an integer.

The [implementation is based on Veltkamp's TwoProduct algorithm](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/src-html/org/apache/commons/math3/util/FastMath.html#line.1613). The usage is similar to standard `Math.pow` function:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath;
// ...
FastMath.pow(3.1417, 2);
```