# Need a better way to write a power function

Tags: c++, function, pow

I have this code for a power function that I created and I was told that there was way to combine the two for loops (one for positive and one for negative exponents) and use a conditional operator

```
double myPow(double base, int exponent) {
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
        result *= base;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i > exponent; --i) {
        result /= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any suggestions as to where to start?

Comment: This should go to [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Code Review but for some reason this stupid dialog still doesn't have it.

Comment: Hey it's not stupid.

Comment: "Any suggestions as to where to start?" define better, because it is subjective.

Comment: Here you have the same question and a good approved answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12541455/4743711

Comment: Off topic. What if `base = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
double myPow(double base, int exponent) {
    double result = 1;
    if (exponent < 0) {
        exponent = -exponent;
        base = 1/base;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve optimally. See Knuth Vol 2 4.6.4 "Evaluation of Powers". Algorithm A would be a good start for you.

Comment: No, because we can optimise x^256 by observing that it is ((((((((x^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2), we only need 8 square operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the absolute value for exponent to loop and then do your operation inside the loop using the conditional operator:

```
double result = 1;
int absExp = std::abs(exponent);
for (int i = 0; i < absExp; i++) {
    exponent < 0 ? // division : // multiplication
}
```

Comment: @Quentin Whoops.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to work in something like this.